# Run Custom Tool for Entity Framework, what does it do?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

In Visual Studio, when working with Entity Framework and applying Run Custom Tool for .tt and .Context.tt files,  What is it and what does it do?

Why it's solving database sync-problems (Sometimes)? and why i should run it for (.tt) before run it for (.Context.tt)?

Answer (score 6):

It's called 'Text Template Transformation Toolkit' and you can use it to create classes out of a meta description (for example). EF uses it to create the classes (context and entity classes) out of the model.

You can also look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Template_Transformation_Toolkit

You can create your own template and have them run. We used it to create an enumeration of of a database table once. More convienient than to do that manually. Later this was deprecated because EF has gained support for enumerations.

Answer (score 0):

Text Template Transformation Toolkit (usually referred to as "T4") is used by developers as part of an application or tool framework to automate the creation of text files with a variety of parameters. These text files can ultimately be any text format, such as code (for example C# and specially generate ADO & Assembly files).
When we update our model from database, T4 generate those required files but Sometimes it doesn't. It could be because of VS version or Our mistakes.
So now we need to generate ADO, Assembly and other required dependent classes and files to run the project error free.

So run custom tool option on .tt & .context.tt gives us option to Generate those files.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30605009)